# An exercise on Weil divisors

Tags: commutative-algebra, divisors-algebraic-geometry

The following is part of the Exercise 3, page 200 of the book: *An Algebraic Introduction to Complex Projective Geometry* by Peskine. It is easy to prove (i), but (ii) is hard for me. Could you give some help?

Let $R$ be a Noetherian normal domain.

(i) If $T$ be a torsion module we put $\mathrm{div}_W(T) = \sum_{\mathrm{ht}(P)=  1} \ell(T_P) [P]$. Show that if $0 \to T' \to T \to T'' \to 0$ is an exact sequence of finitely generated torsion module, then $\mathrm{div}_W(T) = \mathrm{div}_W(T') + \mathrm{div}_W(T'')$.

(ii) Assume there exists an exact sequence $$0 \to L \overset{f}{\to} L' \to T \to 0$$
where $L$ and $L'$ are free modules. Then $\mathrm{div}_W(T) = \mathrm{div}_W(R/\mathrm{det}(f))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (ii), suffices to do this after localizing at a height one prime and so assume $R$ is a dvr. Now, the square matrix $f$ can be put in upper triangular form and then the answer should be clear.

Comment: I have just thought that we should localizing to assume $R$ is an DVR. By the fundamental theorem of finitely generated $R$-modules over PID we have $f(L)$ is a free submodule of $L'$ with the same rank. I feel the fundamental theorem can be applied again, but it is not clear. In your answer, why you can  put the matrix in the upper triangular form  when you don't have a field?

Comment: True for any Euclidean domain. In your case, say $(a_1,\ldots, a_n)$ is a row with entries from a dvr. After interchanging the entries, we may assume that the order  (with respect to the valuation) of $a_1$ is the least. Then, by suitable subtraction, $a_i-x_ia_1=0$ for $i>1$. I hope the rest is clear.